# Exibir ID no form antes de cadastrar php e mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, formulário

Estou fazendo um tela de cadastro , só que eu queria que o sistema já exibisse a ID (id_entidade) que será cadastrado. 
Ao salvar, ele vai perguntar se desejo cadastrar documentos, ai se eu clicar em sim, ele vai para um novo form de cadastro de doc que ao salvar no banco de dados tem que levar a id_entidade

Comment: Falta colocar o que já foi feito (código fonte, não tudo, mas o necessário). Do jeito que está fica muito subjetivo para responder adequadamente.

Comment: Coloquei o código que fiz até o momento.

Comment: Robson se o seu código até o momento for NENHUM fica complicado. Está muito ampla a sua pergunta, pois há várias formas de fazer. Aconselho você a pesquisar mais sobre o php e tentar realizar essa aplicaçao. Pesquise sobre o `header` do php, ele ira direcionar o usuario para um outro ambiente se necessario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos imaginar uma tabela, chamada de entidade, já criada no seu banco. Então, temos:

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|id_entidade integer primary key auto_increment |
|-----------------------------------------------|
|nome varchar(50)                               |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

Isso deve servir para o exemplo. Agora é necessario o formulario para cadastrar usuarios, chamemos de form_usuario.php:

```
<form action="set_user.php" method="post">                                       
    <div class="form-body">
    <h3 class="box-title"><i class="icon-people p-r-10"></i>Dados Principais</h3>
    <hr>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">*Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Sobrenome</label>
            <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>

    <div>
        <!--Campo para redirecionar automaticamente caso queira salvar novo documento-->
        <input type="checkbox" name="novo_documento"> Salvar novo documento 
    </div>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Mostra o proximo valor de **id_entidade** é tranquilo, mas é suscetivel a sobre escrita, pois não há como garantir que ninguem vá tentar se cadastrar simultaneamente. De qualquer forma deixei a função para fazer (comentada). Então vamos para a página set_user.php:

```
<?php
cadastrarUsuario();
//registra novo usuario
function cadastrarUsuario(){
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'teste');
    $status = mysqli_query($conexao, 
    "insert into entidade (nome) values ('". $_POST['nome'] . "')");
    if($status === true){
        //redireciona para o formulario de cadastrar documento
        if(isset($_POST['novo_documento'])){
            ob_get_clean();
            ob_start();
            $ultimo_id = mysqli_insert_id($conexao);
            require_once __DIR__ . '/salvar_documento.php';
            ob_end_flush();


        }else{
            echo 'salvo com sucesso';       
        }
    }
    else{
        echo 'erro ao salvar: ' . mysqli_error($conexao);
    }
}
//função para encontrar o proximo id_entidade na tabela entidade
function proximoId(){
    //dados de conexão com o banco, na ordem, host, usuario, senha, e nome do banco utilizado
    $conexao = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '', 'teste');
    //lista informações da tabela entidade (estrutura), uma delas refere-se ao proximo auto_increment
    $tabela_entidade = mysqli_query($conexao, "SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'entidade'");
    $proximo_id = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tabela_entidade)['Auto_increment'];
    return $proximo_id;
}
```

Nessa página é obtido o id da ultima entidade inserida (para quando for para a pagina inserir novo documento). Além disso tem as funções [ob_get_clean()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-get-clean.php),
[ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-start.php), [ob_end_flush](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-end-flush.php) que são utilizadas para "imprimir" a saida da inclusão do arquivo **salvar_documento.php** (todo o conteudo html).

E por fim o arquivo **salvar_documento.php**, consegue "reconhecer" a variavel `$ultimo_id`, pois foi incluido (require) dentro do arquivo set_user.php (onde foi declarada a variavel `$ultimo_id`). E foi acrescentado um formulario, com um campo oculto representando o id da entidade criada. Ficou assim:

```
<!--Outro formulario-->
<form action="algumapagina.php" method="post">                                       
    <div class="form-body">
    <h3 class="box-title"><i class="icon-people p-r-10"></i>Salvar documento</h3>
    <hr>

    <!--Recupera o id da ultima entidade salva-->
    <label>O id da entidade criada é <?php echo $ultimo_id; ?></label>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_entidade" value="<?php echo $ultimo_id; ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">*Nome</label>
            <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
           </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Sobrenome</label>
            <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <!--/span-->
    </div>

</form>
```

Suponha que todos os arquivos estão no mesmo diretorio.

Para uma referencia das funções **mysqli_*** consulte no [w3c](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp).

Comment: Maravilha!! Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form action="set_user.php" method="post">                                       
                                    <div class="form-body">
                                        <h3 class="box-title"><i class="icon-people p-r-10"></i>Dados Principais</h3>
                                        <hr>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">*Nome</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                                   </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Sobrenome</label>
                                                    <input type="text" id="sobrenome" name="sobrenome" class="form-control" placeholder="">
                                                    </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <!--/span-->
                                        </div>
```

Comment: Uma observação, quando for adicionar mais detalhes, não poste uma resposta, edite a pergunta.